# Insert set values in same order they appear in code

Tags: python, tkinter, set

All I want is insert to listbox items in the same order as in the set. I want it to be inserted like: 'damp'->'camp'->'came' and so on. How can I do that?

```
    gui_dict = tk.Listbox(third_task_window, width=10, height=10)
    words = {'damp', 'camp', 'came', 'lame', 'lime', 'like',
             'cold', 'card', 'cord', 'corm', 'worm', 'warm'}
    for word in words:
        gui_dict.insert(tk.END, word)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are putting them in a set `{}`, which sorts based on hash on creation, put them in a list `[]` instead and they won't be sorted, they will be in the same order you put them in.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
gui_dict = tk.Listbox(root, width=10, height=10)
words = ['damp', 'camp', 'came', 'lame', 'lime', 'like',
         'cold', 'card', 'cord', 'corm', 'worm', 'warm']
for word in words:
    gui_dict.insert(tk.END, word)
gui_dict.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

see python data structures documentation : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html